# How to improve t-sql performance for statement containing IsNull(NullIf(...))

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have inherited the following statement:

```
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT (-1)*SUM(CAST(ISNULL(NULLIF(TOTALMTDLCY,''),0) AS DECIMAL(20,5))) 
FROM TI),0)
```

and although I know what it's trying to do (prevent null values and return 0) I feel there must be a more performant way of doing this?

The reason is that I have a sproc that uses this statement 12 times to get values from different tables, for 40,000 customers (480,000) and then inserts three records for each (1.5M).

This takes around 13 mins to complete - and by gathering some simple stats on the process and totalling them it shows that although the actual time taken for the 12 statements is 00:00.015, the total time is therefore approx 10 mins.

So, my thinking is that if I can speed up this process, then I can speed up my sproc?

Comment: What is the datatype of `TOTALMTDLCY`?

Comment: varchar(25) unfortunately  :(

Comment: ISNULL and NULLIF are not the reason for your perf problem. Why do you think that exactly those functions are the reason?

Comment: This is sa design flaw that will never allow performanct code. If you need decimal numbers for math functions, they MUST be stored as decimals or numerics if you want performance. It is alwys worng to store data in the wrong data type. Additionally when you do this you end up with nonnumeric values inteh filed as well causing addtional problems. You need to fix the database struture, then you don't need to waste time converting to what the data should be stored as.

Comment: If you are using this as a correlated subquery (which the snippet you posted leads me to believe you are) then you are running row-by-agonizing-row and even if you fix the data type issue, performance will be atrocious. Correlated subqueries are a technique of last resort and should not be used when they can be replaced. Essentially they are cursors with all the inherert performance problems.

Comment: @HLGEM: Can't change the db, sadly. 'running row-by-agonizing-row ' is the exact problem, so looking at re-writing the entire sproc, using temp tables...can't see another way :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a varchar to store a numeric value, it will only cause you grief
. Casting all values from varchar to decimal is costly.

Change your table like

```
update TI set TOTALMTDLCY = null where TOTALMTDLCY = ''
alter table TI alter column TOTALMTDLCY DECIMAL(20,5) null
```

Now you can select with no problems

```
select isnull(-sum(TOTALMTDLCY), 0) from TI
```

Comment: Sorry, can't change the table...its been in place since the dinosaurs and there are a lot of other processes running from it :(

Comment: If you can't change the table, you can't tune the script. You can alter the script a bit, but the performance will basically be the same

Answer (score 0):

You may try this if it works..

```
SELECT (-1) * SUM(ISNULL(CAST(TOTALMTDLCY AS DECIMAL(20,5)),0)) FROM TI WHERE TOTALMTDLCY <> ''
```

PS: I currently dont have access to SQL Sever so havent verified it yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
ISNULL(
  -(SELECT SUM(CAST(TOTALMTDLCY as DECIMAL(20,5))) 
     FROM TI where TOTALMTDLCY<>'')
  ,0)
```